# Arranging data for two facet R line plot

Tags: r, facet, linegraph

I am trying to make a two facet line plot as [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14640872/how-to-create-a-faceted-line-graph-using-ggplot). My problem is to arrange data to show desired variable on x-axis. Here is small data set I wanna use.

```
Study,Cat,Dim1,Dim2,Dim3,Dim4
Study1,PK,-3.00,0.99,-0.86,0.46
Study1,US,-4.67,0.76,1.01,0.45
Study2,FL,-2.856,4.15,1.554,0.765
Study2,FL,-8.668,5.907,3.795,4.754
```

I tried to use the following code to draw line graph from this data frame.

```r
plot1 <- ggplot(data = dims, aes(x = Cat, y = Dim1, group = Study)) +
  geom_line() + 
  geom_point() + 
  facet_wrap(~Study)
```

As is clear, I can only use one value column to draw lines. I want to put `Dim1`, `Dim2`, `Dim3`, `Dim4` on `x` axis which I cannot do in this arrangement of data. [tried `c(Dim1, Dim2, Dim3, Dim4)` with no luck]
Probably the solution is to transpose the table but then I cannot reproduce categorization for facet (`Study` in above table) and colour (`Cat` in above table. Any ideas how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
gather(dims, variable, value, -Study, -Cat) %>%
ggplot(aes(x=variable, y=value, group=Cat, col=Cat)) + 
  geom_point() + geom_line() + facet_wrap(~Study)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The solution was quite easy. Just had to think a bit and the re-arranged data looks like this.

```
Study,Cat,Dim,Value
Study1,PK,Dim1,-3
Study1,PK,Dim2,0.99
Study1,PK,Dim3,-0.86
Study1,PK,Dim4,0.46
Study1,US,Dim1,-4.67
Study1,US,Dim2,0.76
Study1,US,Dim3,1.01
Study1,US,Dim4,0.45
Study2,FL,Dim1,-2.856
Study2,FL,Dim2,4.15
Study2,FL,Dim3,1.554
Study2,FL,Dim4,0.765
Study2,FL,Dim1,-8.668
Study2,FL,Dim2,5.907
Study2,FL,Dim3,3.795
Study2,FL,Dim4,4.754
```

After that R produced desire result with this code.

```
plot1 <- ggplot(data=dims, aes(x=Dim, y=Value, colour=Cat, group=Cat)) + geom_line()+ geom_point() + facet_wrap(~Study)
```

Comment: To do this programmatically, use `gather(dat, Dim, Value, -Study, -Cat)`.